# Timed Mute Command 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Role' error

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm making a timed mute command, but i get a lot of errors, the principal one being  :

```js
(node:6584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Role
    at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\user\Desktop\DiscordJSBOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (c:\Users\user\Desktop\DiscordJSBOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildMemberRoleManager.remove (c:\Users\user\Desktop\DiscordJSBOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:125:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Here is the bugged code :

```js
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports = {
    name : 'mute',
    description: 'Mutes given user',
    
    execute(client, message, args) {
        
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS') && message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
            return message.reply('You need permissions to use this command !');
        }
        
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target) {
            const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id)
            
            if(member) {
                const muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
                
                if(muteRole) {
                    const RoleFolder = []
                    const roles = member.roles.cache.map(role => role);

                    roles.forEach(role => {
                        RoleFolder.push(role.id)
                        member.roles.remove(role.id)
                    });
                    member.roles.add(muteRole.id)

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        member.roles.remove(muteRole.id)
                        RoleFolder.forEach(roles => {
                            member.roles.add(roles)
                        })
                    }, ms(args[1]));

                } else {
                    return message.reply('Make sure you have a role nammed "Muted" when trying to mute a member');
                }
            } else {
                return message.reply('There was an error while attempting to get member object of mentioned user !')
            }
        } else {
            return message.reply('You need a user to mute ! ');
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes from the fact that I get all roles from the user, store it and then give it back. I don't know if there is any other way to do it but that's what I found.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Role` is showing up because you are trying to remove a role from a user that the discord API cannot find. This role is the `@everyone` role which all members have.

You also do not need to run `map` on the roles, as you can already iterrate over the cache collection.

The code in your question:

```js
const RoleFolder = []
const roles = member.roles.cache.map(role => role);
roles.forEach(role => {
    RoleFolder.push(role.id)
    member.roles.remove(role.id)
});
```

Can be changed to:

```js
const RoleFolder = []
member.roles.cache.forEach(role => {
    if (role.id === member.guild.id) return;
    RoleFolder.push(role.id)
    member.roles.remove(role.id)
});
```

To ignore the role that doesn't exist in the discord API, you can check for:

`role.id === member.guild.id` or `role.rawPosition === 0`

You can use `return` to skip executing code for that particular role, meaning it isn't added to the RoleFolder, and doesn't try to remove the role.

**Edit:** I would avoid using `role.name === '@everyone'` as a user can create a role called `@everyone` and this would be missed, so I have updated my answer to check for a better condition.